# Is there any naming convention to do the php pass by reference or pass by value?

Tags: php, naming-conventions

I can write a function like :

```
public function removeRubbishTag(&$aString)
```

Also, I can have a function like this:

```
public function removeRubbishTag($aString)
```

But when you look at the params carefully, it is easy to confuse others. Do the PHP community have some naming convention to let people tell easily if a variable is  passByReference or value? Thank you.

Comment: you mean you wanna know the usage of `$` or `&`? would you please explain it more?

Comment: i don't think there is a point in naming these variables diferent ways: when the function is called, you don't care how this var was called inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, consistency in these areas is not a PHP strong suit. But generally the answer to your question is, "no, there is no standard convention".

### Side note:

Things are made more complicated by the fact that pass-by-reference is not quite the same thing as pass-a-reference:

```
$a = array(1,2,3); 
function mutate($b){array_push($b, 1); $b = 2; echo $b;}  
mutate($a); 
var_dump($a); // notice that array is not altered here.
```

Outputs:

```
2
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
```

While this:

```
$a = array(1,2,3); 
function mutate(&$b){array_push($b, 1);}  
mutate($a); 
var_dump($a); // notice that array is altered here.
```

Outputs:

```
2
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(1)
}
```

And this:

```
$a = array(1,2,3); 
//reassigning a reference changes the original value!
function mutate(&$b){array_push($b, 1); $b = 2; echo $b;}  
mutate($a); 
var_dump($a);
```

Outputs:

```
2
int(2)
```

And

```
$a = new stdClass(); 
$a->a = 'a';
// but... modifying an object will always result in the modification: 
function mutate($b){$b->a = "B!"; $b = 2; echo $b;}  
mutate($a); 
var_dump($a);
```

Outputs:

```
2
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(2) "B!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a naming standard for variables being sent into functions in PHP. As for coding standards for PHP, you can reference the PEAR coding standards. http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php

There's no mention of variable naming conventions for this though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no naming-convention. Especially b/c sometimes, as with objects, the pass by ref is implicit.